# How to remove part of line from HTML file

Tags: text-processing, html

I have a file, `events.html`, containing similar lines (among many other):

```html
<td class="EventDate">2021-08-06 12:36:34</td>
```

where date and time strings are different in each line.
In these lines there are **ONLY** `class="EventDate"`
Like to remove from every such line **ONLY** time string.

Additional info:

- system is Debian 9.13 64 bit
- file is 38kb long
- there are about 100 records, each comprising line similar to
  `<td class="EventDate">2021-08-06 12:36:34</td>`
  **BUT** date and time strings are different in each line!
- file contain near the end only one line with (example!) 
  date and time: [2021-08-08 14:16:54 UTC]

For security reasons can not post whole file.

I am neither IT professional nor Linux Guru
but capable of performing various demanding tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xmlstarlet to **ed**it the file, **u**pdating the value with an **x**path expression:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//td[@class="EventDate"]' -x 'substring-before(.," ")' events.html
```

Add `-L` to perform the edits in-place instead of writing the result to standard output.

Ex. given

```
$ cat events.html 
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td class="EventDate">2021-08-06 12:36:34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td class="OtherDate">2021-08-06 12:36:34</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -O -u '//td[@class="EventDate"]' -x 'substring-before(.," ")' events.html 
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td class="EventDate">2021-08-06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell C</td>
    <td class="OtherDate">2021-08-06 12:36:34</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To steeldriver...  

Your recipe generally is O.K. 
but it complains about incorrect sequence of HTML tags. 

Checking my file with https://validator.w3.org/nu/ prints only one error 
"Element marquee not allowed as child of element span in this context." 

Need to modify a bit  events.html  file to get your solution working. 
If I remove offending lines, solution works perfectly O.K!

Comment: @TeWuEsTewues thanks for the feedback - perhaps there are elements that are valid HTML but invalid XML (you could see what `xmlstartlet val events.html` says about that)

Comment: Thre's typo "xmlstar t let"...  
Says not much:
user@linux:/home/user$ xmlstarlet val events.html
events.html - invalid
user@linux:/home/user$
Still digging - Thank you.

Comment: You can preprocess the HTML data into XML compliance using `xmlstarlet fo -H file.html 2>/dev/null`. Feed the output of this into the given `xmlstarlet ed …`

Comment: @roaima thanks that's a good suggestion - pity we don't have a more representative input sample to try

Comment: @steeldriver 
Thank you very much for both of you! 
Solution combined from your answers produced wanted change 
and finally I have what I was targetting at!!!
Well done!